# I need help understanding the npm process?

Tags: npm-scripts

I'm using Visual Studio and I push all my code to github for school projects. I was wondering if I have to run `npm run build` every time I change code for commiting? Thanks

Comment: We don't know what `npm run build` is actually doing for you, so it's hard to say.

Comment: i am building a web app using Vue with npm commands like `npm run serve and `npm run build` than using git push to github

Comment: Just curious if i need to `npm run build` after changes or `git add` `git commit`will do?

Comment: Typically you don't include the output of a build in your commits, in which case it wouldn't matter whether you ran it before, after, both or neither. But again we know nothing about your setup, so can't say.